# Infinite Loop when reading specified number of bytes from binary file

Tags: c++, binary-data

I have a binary file that starts something like this (in hex):

```
FFFF7FFF FFEFFFFF FFFFFFFF 0000454C 0000AA0E 2D2D2D2D 00002892 425A6839 31415926 5359F7B8
FA590000 A4FFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFDFF EBFFFFFF FFFF7FFF FFEFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFE0 
00
```

I'm trying to read in the header with C++. I've got code that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    char tp[9];
    char xt[3];
    uint32_t jdt;
    uint32_t jtm;
    char nm[4];
} Header_1;
int main(){

    Header_1 test;
    ifstream infile("./testbin", ios::in | ios::binary);
    vector<unsigned char> head_bytes(24, 0);
    infile.read((char*)&test, head_bytes.size());

    vector<unsigned char> comp_record(12, 0);
    infile.read((char*)&comp_record, comp_record.size());
    cout <<(char)comp_record[0]<<endl;


}
```

I'm compiling with clang/g++ on macOS 10.13.4, `g++ --version` output below:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Whenever I compile/run the code, I get one of two outcomes depending on whether or not I leave in the last cout line. If it is in there, the program crashes with a Segmentaion Fault 11 (on macOS this appears to be a stack size issue, my stack size is `8192` and I don't see a reason that indicates that increasing it will resolve my problem). If I remove the cout line, I get stuck in an infinite loop.

Given that I give a specified number of bytes to read, I have no idea how I get stuck in a loop nor any idea how I run out of stack space.

Comment: That vector read of `comp_record` is wrong. It should use `comp_record.data()` as the target address. Or `&comp_record[0]`. You're blasting over the members of the vector and the result is puking its guts out on the prior undefined behavior. The prior read is bizarre, making assumptions of the structure size of `Header_1`, and the `head_bytes` vectors is pointless (why not just pass 24 as the second argument to the read?), but the second is a real problem.

Comment: Try printing sizeof Header_1

Comment: @WhozCraig you're absolutely right- that solved the issue. This is what happens when you switch to Python for too long- you forget how array pointers work. Apologies that the prior read is bizarre (you're quite right, it is bizarre)- I took this from a prior piece of code and quickly modified it which is how it ended up like that. I will comment however that I must use 24 as the size of the first read (as it is an exactly 24 byte header) and the struct should always be that size, yes? Regardless, I'm not sure what the etiquette is here, but if you answer I will accept and I have upvoted you.

Comment: The strict size will not be 24 unless you use something like pragma pack.